# Wifi Aware - communication between two Android phones over small distance

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a very particular case that I want to achieve within Android (Kotlin).
I want to build a kind of an analyzer app that detects nearby devices (within ~10meters) and once detected, if my app is running on the second device, I would like to send some message to the first device (something like "Hello, you discovered me, I am phone ID 'xxxx', where 'xxxx' is an ID I define myself).

At first I was reading about WifiAware (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware) "Discover other devices: The API has a mechanism for finding other nearby devices. The process starts when one device publishes one or more discoverable services".

This sounded promising. Essentially:

- Phone 1 would run this discovery trying to detect other devices with
  my published service.
- Phone 2 once detected would send a message to phone 1.
- Of course both phones must have my app running

Edit: to start off simple, the following case is also fine:

- Phone 1 detects phone 2 = phone 1 sends a message to phone 2 "Hello, I found you, I'm phone 1"

However the documentation isn't very detailed and I got stuck at 'obtain the session' chapter and I'm not sure how to instantiate the AwareSession.

But before I dig deeper into this particular technology, I was wondering if this is the right approach for this case and if yes, is there any working example of how this could work? But if no, maybe there are some better alternatives like with bluetooth or gps-location?

Thanks!

Comment: `"Hello, you discovered me` ? `"Hello, I discovered you"` ? Or do i read your scenario wrong?

Comment: @blackapps - it would be perfect if actually both phones were publishers and receivers at the same time, so when both are in range, both get notifications. But for initial tests, I wanted phone 1 to be publisher and phone 2 to be receiver. Once phone 2 is in range, phone 2 sends phone 1 a message. To make my app work, both phones must know their assigned IDs

Comment: `Once phone 2 is in range, phone 2 sends phone 1 a message. ` Yes we knew that . So it will send: "Hello, I discovered you" .

Comment: `I wanted phone 1 to be publisher and phone 2 to be receiver. Once phone 2 is in range, phone 2 sends phone 1 a message. ` I cannot follow you. What would phone 1 publish?

Comment: `Phone 1 would run this discovery trying to detect other devices with my published service.
Phone 2 once detected would send a message to phone 1.` ?? If phone 1 detects phone 2 then how would it tell phone 2 to send a message? ??

Comment: Alright, let's keep it simple. Phone 1 detects phone 2 = phone 1 sends message to phone 2 "Hello, I'm phone 1"

Comment: @Keran any update on this please let me know im also trying the same